# bootstrap custom column widths stack rather than shrink on resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap grid layout as follows:

A col-sm-10 surrounded by a col-sm-1 on each side.

```
+----+----------------------------+----+
|sm-1| sm-10                      |sm-1|
+----+----------------------------+----+
```

It's also using the list-group styling but I don't think that matters.

I need the col-sm-1 to be smaller than they are by default, and I remove padding, so I am overriding the style:

I change the col-sm-1 to a width of 4%, and the col-sm-10 to a width of 92%:

```
.custom > .list-group-item > .col-sm-1 {
    width: 4%;
  background-color: green;
}
.custom > .list-group-item > .col-sm-10 {
    width: 92%;
  background-color: blue;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="custom list-group">
    <div class="row list-group-item">

      <div class="col-sm-1">
       xx
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-10">
        MAIN
      </div>


      <div class="col-sm-1">
        xx
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

THE ISSUE:

I want the columns to stay in one row, with my customizations the columns "break" and "stack" rather than just shrinking and staying on one line like the standard bootstrap layout does.  You can see this in the link below, by dragging the window smaller:

http://www.bootply.com/9CVohbVSTL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because the `sm` columns no longer float left when the screen width is less than 768px so they stack vertically. Use the `xs` columns instead. Also, the padding is not being removed from the columns themselves.

```
.custom > .list-group-item > div {
  padding: 0px;
}
.custom > .list-group-item > .col-xs-1 {
  width: 4%;
  background-color: green;
}
.custom > .list-group-item > .col-xs-10 {
  width: 92%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/aOgEGLXox9

This works, but I think it would be better to not use the Bootstrap columns at all in this case and just use custom CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is another way to solve this issue

*LESS equation to calculate column widths:*

*width: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));*

example:

```
1 column / 12 grid-columns = 8.33% * 1170px = 97.5px
2 columns / 12 grid-columns = 16.67% * 1170px = 195px
3 columns / 12 grid-columns = 25% * 1170px = 292.5px
Etc…
```

Using above method i create one example at **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/RGwKGZ?editors=1100)**

CSS:

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.custom > .list-group-item {
  /* padding: 0px; */
}

.custom > .list-group-item > .col-xs-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.custom > .list-group-item > .col-sm-1 {
  width: 6.33%;
  background-color: green;
}

.custom > .list-group-item > .col-sm-10 {
  width: 87.33%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.standard > .list-group-item > .col-sm-1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.standard > .list-group-item > .col-sm-10 {
  background-color: blue;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .custom > .list-group-item > .col-xs-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

I hope this information might be help in undestanding the calculation of custom column widths

Enjoy :)